# How to draw a arrow from one object to another object in an Editor in Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to draw an arrow from one object to another object.before that I need to click on the'Connect' button to draw the line.

for drawing that I used below snippet, but it does not work.

```
Actions builder = new Actions(webDriver);

Action drawAction = builder.moveToElement(from, from.getLocation().getX(), 

from.getLocation().getY())

                .click()

                .moveByOffset(to.getLocation().getX(), 

to.getLocation().getY())

                .doubleClick()

                .build();
```

from - source element
to   - destination(end location)

Anyone can tell what is the issue with this code ?

Comment: Just to confirm the expected functionality.  The draw option requires to you click at one point and then double click at another point to draw an arrow, you aren't required to hold the left mouse button down while drawing it?

Comment: The main error I see right now is that you call `.build()`, but you never call `.perform()`

Comment: though I perform() the action it giving the below information in the console.
Jun 17, 2019 4:00:26 PM org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions moveToElement
INFO: When using the W3C Action commands, offsets are from the center of element

Comment: Simply I get the x and y co-ordination by using getLocation() in-built method. but it seems like , it expects the center co-ordination of the elements, is not it ?

Comment: @PiyumRangana after method build, have u method `perform()`? in c# this code works `var canvas = driver.FindElement(By.Id("catch"));
            var action = new Actions(driver).ClickAndHold(canvas).MoveByOffset(100, 100);
            action.Build().Perform();`

Comment: yes, @Ardesco I have missed it to add to the above code.

Comment: @tCode it worked for me. Modified the code as below 
Action drawAction = builder.clickAndHold(from)
                .moveToElement(to)
                .click()
                .build();
        drawAction.perform();

Thanks a lot for the idea

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call the `perform()` method

```
drawAction.perform();
```